# HTML image is not loading

Tags: html, image

An image in an `img` tag with a `src` attribute is not loading in the html page even though I gave the correct path.

```
<div class="row" id="center">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><img src="C:\Users\aNas kOdUr\Pictures\fk-logo_9fddff.png" height="50"/> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post you code here. Otherwise nobody can help you. Also please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are using the physical path of the file. But you have to use the virtual path instead. Like you can copy the `fk-logo_9fddff.png` file in a folder named `images` which is in the same folder as your `html` and then just use `<img src="images/fk-logo_9fddff.png" height="50"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into relative paths

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

The src attribute may need to be something like

```
<img src="../my.jpg" />
```

You may also want to define a root folder to your site using the Base tag

https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_base.asp

That way you can use the same path regardless of what part of the site the page is in.